# Powershell or other Windows method to copy datestamped html file to network share

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

Im new to powershell - so serious noob.

But I wanted to see if anyone could help in doing the following.

We have a folder on a server that has reports written to it every night.
The reports are named in the following format:
`DiskSpaceReport_26102012.html`
and location of `C:\Powershell\WebReport\`

I would like a PS script to copy these 1 of these files from the folder using a daterange of -8 Days from the date the script runs - the script would be run as part of a windows scheduled task or through SQL Agent job.

So at present there are 8 files in the folder dating from `Friday 26 Oct` to `Friday 19th Oct`.
I would like the process to run today and copy the file -8 days back from todays date.
So copy the file named `DiskSpaceReport_19102012.html`

And this process should repeat weekly on friday and copy the last file from 8 days ago.
The copy is to a network share

`\\Server01\Powershell\Webreports_Archive`

And as I mentioned in title I dont mind if this is easier to do via robocopy in a batch file for example.
Would prefer it via PS though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do what you want:

```
$pastdays = -8
$pastdate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays($pastdays)
$filename = "DiskSpaceReport_" + $pastdate.Day + $pastdate.Month + $pastdate.Year+".html"
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Powershell\WebReport\$($filename)" "\\Server01\Powershell\Webreports_Archive"
```

regards
Jon

Comment: Excellent - does exactly what is says on the TIN !